# Failed to read extended partition table (offset=x): Invalid argument bad disk partition size

Tags: filesystems, partition, disk, testdisk

I have a 500GB HDD that will only boot into grub rescue. It appears the partition table has become corrupt as fdisk is reporting one partition being 3.6T. I have run testdisk (results below) but not sure how to proceed, all i need to be able to do is mount the partition to get some files off it.

```
Failed to read extended partition table (offset=964032512): Invalid argument
Disk /dev/sde: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 122096646 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00052d57

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sde1  *         2048 964032511 964030464  3.6T 83 Linux
/dev/sde2       964032512 976773167  12740656 48.6G  5 Extended
```

```
parted /dev/sde print
Error: Cannot have a partition outside the disk!
Ignore/Cancel?
Ignore/Cancel?
Ignore/Cancel? i
Error: Cannot have a partition outside the disk!
Ignore/Cancel?
Ignore/Cancel?
Ignore/Cancel? i
Error: Cannot have a partition outside the disk!
Ignore/Cancel? i
Error: Invalid argument during seek for read on /dev/sde
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? i
Error: Invalid partition table on /dev/sde -- wrong signature 6475.
Ignore/Cancel? i
Error: Cannot have a partition outside the disk!
Ignore/Cancel? i
Model: WDC WD50 03AZEX-00MK2A0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sde: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      8389kB  3949GB  3949GB  primary                boot
 2      3949GB  4001GB  52.2GB  extended
```

```
TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sde - 500 GB / 465 GiB - CHS 7600 255 63

The harddisk (500 GB / 465 GiB) seems too small! (< 15 TB / 13 TiB)
Check the harddisk size: HD jumpers settings, BIOS detection...

The following partitions can't be recovered:
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>  Linux                 1144  87 32  8645  91 22  120503808
   Linux                 1144 148 29  8645 152 19  120503808
   Linux                 1144 172 53  8645 176 43  120503808
   Linux                 1144 217 34  8645 221 24  120503808
   Linux                 1144 221 38  8645 225 28  120503808
   Linux                 1145 145 25  8646 149 15  120503808
   Linux                 1145 202 18  8646 206  8  120503808
   Linux                 1145 234 50  8646 238 40  120503808
   HPFS - NTFS          203486  30 44 230431  25 50  432871117
   HPFS - NTFS          203518 253 43 230463 248 49  432871117

[ Continue ]
ext4 blocksize=4096 Large_file Sparse_SB Recover, 493 GB / 459 GiB
```

Answer (score 0):

The partition table seems to be made for a sector size of 512 bytes, however, the logical sector size of your disk is is 4096 bytes. This sometimes happens with USB enclosures that emulate a wrong logical sector size, or when making a full copy using `dd` to a device with different sector size.

You can work around it with `losetup`:

```
losetup --find --show --partscan --sector-size=512 /dev/sde
```

Then see if the resulting loop device has usable partitions.

For a proper fix, you'll have to re-create the partition table with the new sector size. The loop device should help to print the correct partition offsets and sizes (in bytes).